# Can't create Signed APK

Tags: android, apk, android-proguard, signed

I have been developing an application with Android Studio, tested, and I'm ready to publish to Google Play.

When I tried to create a signed APK, after creating the keys, the gradle build stops with the following message:

```
Please correct the above warnings first.
```

After a lot of research, I found that the problem may be in the build.gradle (Module: app) and I read that is missing this this lines:

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```

But, even with this lines, it wont works. Here is the message:

[image: Error]

EDIT:

heres my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.companyname.appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2018.05.11 v2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':componentsutils')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.2'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'br.com.livroandroid:android-utils:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
}
```

EDIT 2

Going deeper in the build error, I found this Stacktrace:

[image: StackTrace error]

Comment: post the error logs...i think the error from proguard config

Comment: The `lintOptions` might not do any good for your. Look for the _ProGuard_ output and resolve all the warnings there. You could also check if this is the issue by just setting `minifyEnabled` to `false` and build this. It's the only difference between your release and dubug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem with ProGuard configuration.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) is the description of ProGuard on android developers site, basically it is a tool that does a few things, including removing of code that it thinks is unnecessary. The problem is that often it removes code that is necessary to run or even build, like in your case.
To fix this problem you can do two things.

1. Disable ProGuard:

Add

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

to your app level build.gradle file.

2. Provide rules, so ProGuard keeps necessary files.

In this case you keep your setup

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And you need to edit the `proguard-rules.pro` file. It should be located in the same directory as your app level `build.gradle` file. Usually, every library provides proguard rules on their web site, for example [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) has them at the bottom of the page. Go through all your libs and add all necessary rules to your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this error today and wasted hours. I did this

> 1. Updated all app dependencies like `google.gms` and `google.support` libraries.
> 2. Updated gradle wrapper version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.
> 3. Updated gradle plugin version in project level `build.gradle`.

If you ask me where you find latest version

**You will get suggestion in all of these three, just accept suggestion with `alt + enter` key.**